# What screenkey/key-mon clones exist for Windows?

Tags: windows, screencasts

I am planning a screencast and would prefer to use PuTTY from my Windows 7 (x64) box. However, I want the audience to see what keys I am pressing on screen.

For Linux there are screenkey or key-mon, but what can I use on Windows? I don't care if it is shareware, but FLOSS would still be preferred.

NB: this is not about the *best* program, it is asking for any such program as I haven't been able to find one even after putting considerable effort into the search. This is also not about software to record the screen contents in any way.

---

Meanwhile I also found [KeyJedi](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/luKa/archive/2010/09/21/keyboard-jedi-on-windows7-64-bit.aspx), but the program won't show just any key presses. It only shows particular ones (e.g. with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) so it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This [script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/KeyboardOnScreen.htm) shows a mock keyboard which will highlight the key as they're pressed. [This](http://web.archive.org/web/20130701070044/http://www.romeosa.com/osdHotkey/help.html) is a compiled script that will display what key are being pressed. Both should cover your need. FYI, I found them using 'autohotkey show pressed key' since I remembered autohotkey sample showing the first script. Turns out googling 'show pressed key' will do the trick too.

Comment: second link has registration wall. pls fix

Comment: @beppe9000 Thanks for the information, updated the link.